# Pyramid's auth_tkt

Tags: python, security, authentication, token, pyramid

When using Pyramid's AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy is there any way to obtain the value of the "auth_tkt" cookie that is set in the Headers returned by the pyramid.security.remember() function. I'm trying to do so in order to return the cookie's value in the body of the response.

Lastly, is this a bad idea to begin with? What I'm trying to do is leverage Pyramid's pre-buil AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy but to return the auth_tkt cookie that is set in the response header in the body to be used and set by an iOS client.

Comment: Sounds like AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy is not exactly what you need. I'd suggest subclassing the thing and customize for your needs by overriding relevant methods or just copy-paste the whole thing and edit in-place. It's not much code.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Yeah, that's what I was trying to avoid. I know it's not much code but I was hoping there was a way to get around it. I'm just surprised there isn't a built in Auth policy so that one may return a JSON token to a mobile client. Thanks for your suggestion though.